# Solution or approximation to $\int x^{-a} \Gamma\left( b, c x^{-d} + e \right) dx$

Tags: integration, approximation-theory, integral-transforms, gamma-function, integral-operators

I'm looking for a solution or approximation to the following indefinite integral $$\int x^{-a} \Gamma\left( b, c x^{-d} + e \right) dx.$$

I've tried Mathematica, but it does not converge to a solution. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: there is a closed-form solution for $e=0$, but not for nonzero $e$ (and arbitrary exponents, $a,d$)

Comment: The mentioned closed form solution for $e=0$ is here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415584/solution-to-int-x-a-gamma-left-b-c-x-d-right-dx

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, would an approximation be possible?

Comment: For $x\to\infty$, use Taylor series in $z$ of $\Gamma(b, z+e)$ and integrate term by term. For $y=(c x^{-d}+e) \to \infty$, use [asymptotic expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E2) of $\Gamma(b,y)$ and integrate term by term. Or do you need something more sophisticated?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine, Dear, the point is that nor $x$ nor $y = (cx^{−d}+e)$ tend to $\infty$. So, I would go with the "more sophisticated" solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is missing information about what regime of approximation you are interested in. Away from singular limits, where some parameter is going to infinity, you can also just apply numerical integration.

Answer (score 1):

*Could this be workable ? *

$$I=\int x^{-a} \Gamma\left( b, c x^{-d} + e \right) \,dx$$
Let $c x^{-d}=t$ and $\alpha=\frac{a-d-1}{d}$ to make
$$I=-\frac 1 d \,c^{\frac{1-a}{d}}\int t^\alpha \,\,\Gamma (b,t+e)\,dt$$ Expand as a series of $e$ around $e=0$
$$\Gamma (b,t+e)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n\, e^n$$ where

$$A_n=-\frac{(n-1)  (t+n-b-1)\,A_{n-1}+(n-2)\,A_{n-2}}{n(n-1)t }$$
with
$$A_0=\Gamma (b,t) \qquad \qquad A_1=-e^{-t}\, t^{b-1}$$

Comment: Please, complete the answer.

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo? My very first line is a question to you. Did you try something ? I am curious to know

Comment: Dear, I haven't tried anything yet. However your answer seems to be the way to a solution. That is why I asked if you could go on with your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo. Please try it and let us discuss later